# Find out which firestore batch action failed and what data was written to db?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function to create a character that has 2 writes to firestore to create character and create username (I create username to then check if it already exists i.e. enforcing unique usernames).

```
try {
  const characterPrivateRef = firestore().doc(`characters/${uid}`);
  const usernameRef = firestore().doc(`usernames/${username}`);
  firestore().batch().batch.create(characterRef, {...characterData});
  firestore().batch().batch.create(characterPrivateRef, {...usernameData});

  await firestore().batch().commit();
  // How can I get data written to each firestore document from batch 
  here?
} catch (e) {

  // How can I check what batch failed here i.e. if it was username I 
  want to show error saying something like ("Username already exists")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a batch write, it means that you trying to write the data to the Firestore database atomic, which means that either all operations succeed or all operations fail. As far as I know, there is no way to know which one of those two operations within the batch has failed. What you can do instead, is to attach a complete listener and get the error message once the batch operation fails. If you want to know which operation fails, you should write the data separately, as two different write operations.